# Kinect constantly increasing joint position value

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have a application in c# for skeleton tracking. It is showing (visualizing) the skeleton properly, but when I want to show the actual value of chosen joint, it is not working right.

EXAMPLE:
In my app I have a button that should get the actual Y position of hip center and a textbox where this value should be displayed. I am standing still in front of kinect and everytime I click the button, the value changes (even though I am not moving).

1. click : -56,236589
2. click : -89,214563
3. click : -100,254789

and so on.

Below is full source code of my app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Windows; 
using System.Windows.Media; 
using Microsoft.Kinect; 
using System.IO;
using Encog.Neural.Networks;
using Encog.Neural.Networks.Layers;
using Encog.Engine.Network.Activation;
using Encog.ML.Data;
using Encog.Neural.Networks.Training.Propagation.Resilient;
using Encog.ML.Train;
using Encog.ML.Data.Basic;
using Encog.ML.SVM;
using Encog.ML.SVM.Training;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    KinectSensor sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
    private double shoulderRightY;
    private double shoulderLeftY;
    private double headY;
    private double hipY;

    Joint rightShoulder = new Joint();
    Joint leftShoulder = new Joint();
    Joint head = new Joint();
    Joint hip = new Joint();



    #region "Variables"
    /// <summary>
    /// Thickness of body center ellipse
    /// </summary>
    private const double BodyCenterThickness = 10;

    /// <summary>
    /// Thickness of clip edge rectangles
    /// </summary>
    private const double ClipBoundsThickness = 10;

    /// <summary>
    /// Brush used to draw skeleton center point
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Brush centerPointBrush = Brushes.Blue;

    /// <summary>
    /// Brush used for drawing joints that are currently tracked
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Brush trackedJointBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 68, 192, 68));

    /// <summary>
    /// Brush used for drawing joints that are currently inferred
    /// </summary>        
    private readonly Brush inferredJointBrush = Brushes.Yellow;

    /// <summary>
    /// Pen used for drawing bones that are currently tracked
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Pen trackedBonePen = new Pen(Brushes.Green, 6);

    /// <summary>
    /// Pen used for drawing bones that are currently inferred
    /// </summary>        
    private readonly Pen inferredBonePen = new Pen(Brushes.Gray, 1);

    /// <summary>
    /// Drawing image that we will display
    /// </summary>
    private DrawingImage imageSource;

    /// <summary>
    /// Thickness of drawn joint lines
    /// </summary>
    private const double JointThickness = 3;


    /// <summary>
    /// Drawing group for skeleton rendering output
    /// </summary>
    private DrawingGroup drawingGroup;
    /// <summary>
    /// Width of output drawing
    /// </summary>
    private const float RenderWidth = 640.0f;

    /// <summary>
    /// Height of our output drawing
    /// </summary>
    private const float RenderHeight = 480.0f;
    #endregion

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //After Initialization subscribe to the loaded event of the form 
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;

        //After Initialization subscribe to the unloaded event of the form
        //We use this event to stop the sensor when the application is being closed.
        Unloaded += MainWindow_Unloaded;


    }

    void MainWindow_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //stop the Sestor 
        sensor.Stop();

    }


    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //Create a Drawing Group that will be used for Drawing 
        this.drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();

        //Create an image Source that will display our skeleton
        this.imageSource = new DrawingImage(this.drawingGroup);

        //Display the Image in our Image control
        Image.Source = imageSource;

        try
        {
            //Check if the Sensor is Connected
            if (sensor.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
            {
                //Start the Sensor
                sensor.Start();
                //Tell Kinect Sensor to use the Default Mode(Human Skeleton Standing) || Seated(Human Skeleton Sitting Down)
                sensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Default;
                //Subscribe to te  Sensor's SkeletonFrameready event to track the joins and create the joins to display on our image control
                sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += sensor_SkeletonFrameReady;
                //nice message with Colors to alert you if your sensor is working or not
                Message.Text = "Kinect Ready";
                Message.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                Message.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

                // Turn on the skeleton stream to receive skeleton frames
                this.sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
            }
            else if (sensor.Status == KinectStatus.Disconnected)
            {
                //nice message with Colors to alert you if your sensor is working or not
                Message.Text = "Kinect Sensor is not Connected";
                Message.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
                Message.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

            }
            else if (sensor.Status == KinectStatus.NotPowered)
            {//nice message with Colors to alert you if your sensor is working or not
                Message.Text = "Kinect Sensor is not Powered";
                Message.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                Message.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    //When the Skeleton is Ready it must draw the Skeleton
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void sensor_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        //declare an array of Skeletons
        Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[1];

        //Opens a SkeletonFrame object, which contains one frame of skeleton data.
        using (SkeletonFrame skeletonframe = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            //Check if the Frame is Indeed open 
            if (skeletonframe != null)
            {

                skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonframe.SkeletonArrayLength];

                // Copies skeleton data to an array of Skeletons, where each Skeleton contains a collection of the joints.
                skeletonframe.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);

                //draw the Skeleton based on the Default Mode(Standing), "Seated"
                if (sensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode == SkeletonTrackingMode.Default)
                {
                    //Draw standing Skeleton
                    DrawStandingSkeletons(skeletons);
                }
                else if (sensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode == SkeletonTrackingMode.Seated)
                {
                    //Draw a Seated Skeleton with 10 joints
                    DrawSeatedSkeletons(skeletons);
                }
            }
        }


            foreach (Skeleton skeleton in skeletons)
            {
                if (skeleton != null)
                {
                    hip = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipCenter];
                    rightShoulder = skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight];
                    leftShoulder = skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft];
                    head = skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head];


                    shoulderRightY += rightShoulder.Position.Y;
                    shoulderLeftY += leftShoulder.Position.Y;
                    headY += head.Position.Y;
                    hipY += hip.Position.Y;


                }


        }

                }







    // button click method
    private void stoji_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(@"E:\KINECT\inputs.txt", shoulderRightY + " " + shoulderLeftY + " " + headY + " " + hipY + Environment.NewLine);
        File.AppendAllText(@"E:\KINECT\outputs.txt", "1" + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void sedi_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(@"E:\KINECT\inputs.txt", shoulderRightY + " " + shoulderLeftY + " " + headY + " " + hipY + Environment.NewLine);
        File.AppendAllText(@"E:\KINECT\outputs.txt", "2" + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void lezi_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(@"E:\KINECT\inputs.txt", shoulderRightY + " " + shoulderLeftY + " " + headY + " " + hipY + Environment.NewLine);
        File.AppendAllText(@"E:\KINECT\outputs.txt", "3" + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    //Thi Function Draws the Standing  or Default Skeleton
    private void DrawStandingSkeletons(Skeleton[] skeletons)
    {

        using (DrawingContext dc = this.drawingGroup.Open())
        {
            //Draw a Transparent background to set the render size or our Canvas
            dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));

            //If the skeleton Array has items 
            if (skeletons.Length != 0)
            {
                //Loop through the Skeleton joins
                foreach (Skeleton skel in skeletons)
                {
                    RenderClippedEdges(skel, dc);

                    if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                    {
                        this.DrawBonesAndJoints(skel, dc);


                    }
                    else if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.PositionOnly)
                    {
                        dc.DrawEllipse(this.centerPointBrush,
                                       null,
                                       this.SkeletonPointToScreen(skel.Position), BodyCenterThickness, BodyCenterThickness);

                    }

                }


            }

            //Prevent Drawing outside the canvas 
            this.drawingGroup.ClipGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));

        }
    }


    private void DrawSeatedSkeletons(Skeleton[] skeletons)
    {

        using (DrawingContext dc = this.drawingGroup.Open())
        {
            //Draw a Transparent background to set the render size 
            dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));

            if (skeletons.Length != 0)
            {
                foreach (Skeleton skel in skeletons)
                {
                    RenderClippedEdges(skel, dc);

                    if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                    {
                        this.DrawBonesAndJoints(skel, dc);


                    }
                    else if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.PositionOnly)
                    {
                        dc.DrawEllipse(this.centerPointBrush,
                                       null,
                                       this.SkeletonPointToScreen(skel.Position), BodyCenterThickness, BodyCenterThickness);

                    }

                }


            }

            //Prevent Drawing outside the canvas 
            this.drawingGroup.ClipGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));

        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Draws indicators to show which edges are clipping skeleton data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="skeleton">skeleton to draw clipping information for</param>
    /// <param name="drawingContext">drawing context to draw to</param>
    private static void RenderClippedEdges(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Bottom))
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                Brushes.Red,
                null,
                new Rect(0, RenderHeight - ClipBoundsThickness, RenderWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));
        }

        if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Top))
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                Brushes.Red,
                null,
                new Rect(0, 0, RenderWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));
        }

        if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Left))
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                Brushes.Red,
                null,
                new Rect(0, 0, ClipBoundsThickness, RenderHeight));
        }

        if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Right))
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                Brushes.Red,
                null,
                new Rect(RenderWidth - ClipBoundsThickness, 0, ClipBoundsThickness, RenderHeight));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a skeleton's bones and joints
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="skeleton">skeleton to draw</param>
    /// <param name="drawingContext">drawing context to draw to</param>
    private void DrawBonesAndJoints(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        // Render Torso
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.Head, JointType.ShoulderCenter);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderRight);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.Spine);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.Spine, JointType.HipCenter);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipRight);

        // Left Arm
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ElbowLeft, JointType.WristLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft);

        // Right Arm
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ElbowRight, JointType.WristRight);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight);

        // Left Leg
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.KneeLeft, JointType.AnkleLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft);

        // Right Leg
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.KneeRight, JointType.AnkleRight);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight);



        // Render Joints
        foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
        {
            Brush drawBrush = null;

            if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                drawBrush = this.trackedJointBrush;
            }
            else if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred)
            {
                drawBrush = this.inferredJointBrush;
            }

            if (drawBrush != null)
            {
                drawingContext.DrawEllipse(drawBrush, null, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint.Position), JointThickness, JointThickness);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a bone line between two joints
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="skeleton">skeleton to draw bones from</param>
    /// <param name="drawingContext">drawing context to draw to</param>
    /// <param name="jointType0">joint to start drawing from</param>
    /// <param name="jointType1">joint to end drawing at</param>
    private void DrawBone(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext, JointType jointType0, JointType jointType1)
    {
        Joint joint0 = skeleton.Joints[jointType0];
        Joint joint1 = skeleton.Joints[jointType1];

        // If we can't find either of these joints, exit
        if (joint0.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked || joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Don't draw if both points are inferred
        if (joint0.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred && joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred)
        {
            return;
        }

        // We assume all drawn bones are inferred unless BOTH joints are tracked
        Pen drawPen = this.inferredBonePen;

        if (joint0.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked && joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
        {
            drawPen = this.trackedBonePen;
        }

        drawingContext.DrawLine(drawPen, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint0.Position), this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint1.Position));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Maps a SkeletonPoint to lie within our render space and converts to Point
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="skelpoint">point to map</param>
    /// <returns>mapped point</returns>
    private Point SkeletonPointToScreen(SkeletonPoint skelpoint)
    {
        // Convert point to depth space.  
        // We are not using depth directly, but we do want the points in our 640x480 output resolution.
        DepthImagePoint depthPoint = this.sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(skelpoint, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
        return new Point(depthPoint.X, depthPoint.Y);
    }

    private void classify_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        double detect=Program.siet();
        vysledok.Text = detect.ToString();
    }

    private void testexample_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       /* if (File.Exists(@"E:\KINECT\test.txt"))
        {
            File.Delete(@"E:\KINECT\test.txt");
        }*/
        File.AppendAllText(@"E:\KINECT\test.txt", shoulderRightY + " " + shoulderLeftY + " " + headY + " " + hipY + Environment.NewLine);

    }

    private void deletedata_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        File.Delete(@"E:\KINECT\inputs.txt");
        File.Delete(@"E:\KINECT\outputs.txt");
    }

    private void vymaztest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        File.Delete(@"E:\KINECT\test.txt");
        File.Delete(@"E:\KINECT\testout.txt");
    }

    private void yhip_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ybox.Text = hipY.ToString();
    }

    }
}
```

Can anyone pleeease tell me what can I do to fix this bug?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use

```
hipY += hip.Position.Y
```

Unless you stand accurate at the center (Position.Y = 0) it is correct, that hipY changes every time.

I think you want

```
hipY = hip.Position.Y
```

And by the way:

- You should ensure that the skeleton is tracked and the hip joint is tracked when you set the hip position.
- You should ensure that you track the same skeleton when you set the
  hip position.